# ActiveX embedded in Firefox Plugin

Tags: c#, firefox, firefox-addon, activex

I have a library (developed by my company) written in C# and compiled to be an ActiveX. The lib is really complex and rewriting it is likely out of discussion.
There is a way to use the library embedded or wrapped by a plugin to use the function in it?

Comment: If you make it a shared library you can use js-ctypes to tap into it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/ctypes.open